# Pandas Dataframe - possible to remove list formatting from values inside?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list that looks like this:

```
some_list = [["breakfast", ["apple", 'pear', 'cereal']], ["dinner", ["ham", 'burger', 'chicken wings']]]
```

I've made it a Pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(some_list,columns=['one', 'two'])
```

Printing it displays this:

```
         one                           two
0  breakfast           [apple, pear, rice]
1     dinner  [ham, burger, chicken wings]
```

**My question**

Is there some way that I can remove the list formatting (i.e. the '[' and ']') from the items in column two?

Comment: if they are gonna be `list` type, then they will have those brackets

Comment: `df['two'] = df['two'].agg(','.join)`

Comment: Thank you David! That worked great! I'd love to accept this as the answer if you would like to copy it to the answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just convert the column to string and join it with comma like this.

```
df.two = df.two.str.join(',')
```

The output will be:

```
         one                       two
0  breakfast         apple,pear,cereal
1     dinner  ham,burger,chicken wings
```

In the above example, if the lists containing object(s) of types other than str, the result will produce a NaN

example:

```
import pandas as pd
some_list = [["breakfast", ["apple", 'pear', 'cereal']],
             ["dinner", ["ham", 'burger', 'chicken wings']],
             ["lunch", [20, 'pasta', 'french fries']]]

df = pd.DataFrame(some_list,columns=['one', 'two'])
df.two = df.two.str.join(',')
print (df)
```

Output will be:

```
         one                       two
0  breakfast         apple,pear,cereal
1     dinner  ham,burger,chicken wings
2      lunch                       NaN
```

Alternatively, you can use map and join to expand it. This will not result in NaN for the 3rd row (lunch)

```
import pandas as pd
some_list = [["breakfast", ["apple", 'pear', 'cereal']],
             ["dinner", ["ham", 'burger', 'chicken wings']],
             ["lunch", [20, 'pasta', 'french fries']]]

df = pd.DataFrame(some_list,columns=['one', 'two'])
#df.two = df.two.str.join(',')

df['two'] = [','.join(map(str, x)) for x in df['two']]
print (df)
```

If you are more familiar with apply and lambda, then:

```
df['two'] = df['two'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))
```

output will be:

```
         one                       two
0  breakfast         apple,pear,cereal
1     dinner  ham,burger,chicken wings
2      lunch     20,pasta,french fries
```

Comment: The alternative solution doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Good answer accounting for integers/floats.

Answer (score 2):

You can join the list values to a string with:

```
df['two'] = df['two'].agg(','.join)
```

Comment: This is probably what the OP wants, but note that this is not just "removing formatting", it is actually changing the stored value from a list to a string.

Comment: @BrenBarn that is true. There probably are not any ways to change the formatting with `pd.set_option()` if I had to guess.

Comment: This option is not working for a list item `["lunch", [20, 'pasta', 'french fries']]`

Comment: That is correct. It would not work with list items that integers or strings.

Comment: I was able to solve this by converting it to pd.Series. Here's how it worked. `df['two'] = pd.Series(df['two']).agg(','.join)`. This will take care of the numbers and strings combination.

Comment: Interesting and good find. That may be the easiest way then. Feel free to include that in your answer.